# preg_match_all to show multiple results

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get this messages (METAR) from a page and show everything just in other php file without the styles and extra info.
At the moment I'm using this code:

```
<?php
$options = array('http' => array(
'method'  => 'GET',
));

$config= stream_context_create($options);
$config_final=file_get_contents('http://www.smn.gov.ar/mensajes/index.php?observacion=metar&operacion=consultar&87582=on&87641=on&87750=on&87765=on&87222=on&87761=on&87860=on&87395=on&87344=on&87166=on&87904=on&87571=on&87347=on&87803=on&87576=on&87162=on&87532=on&87497=on&87097=on&87046=on&87548=on&87217=on&87506=on&87692=on&87418=on&87574=on&87715=on&87374=on&87289=on&87852=on&87178=on&87896=on&87823=on&87270=on&87155=on&87453=on&87925=on&87934=on&87480=on&87047=on&87553=on&87311=on&87909=on&87436=on&87509=on&87912=on&87623=on&87444=on&87129=on&87371=on&87645=on&87022=on&87127=on&87828=on&87121=on&87938=on&87791=on&87448=on',false, $config);
preg_match_all("|<td width=\"100%\">METAR (.*)</td>|sU", $config_final, $tiempo);
echo $tiempo[1][0];
?>

</div>
```

Using that code I can get only the first METAR, Waht I need is to see all of them in different lines, like showing different results.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use an HTML parse such as `DOMDocument`? its also good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you utilize PHP's built in HTML Parsers for this, in particular the `DOMDocument`, and use `DOMXpath` to search for those needle.

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.smn.gov.ar/mensajes/index.php?observacion=metar&operacion=consultar&87582=on&87641=on&87750=on&87765=on&87222=on&87761=on&87860=on&87395=on&87344=on&87166=on&87904=on&87571=on&87347=on&87803=on&87576=on&87162=on&87532=on&87497=on&87097=on&87046=on&87548=on&87217=on&87506=on&87692=on&87418=on&87574=on&87715=on&87374=on&87289=on&87852=on&87178=on&87896=on&87823=on&87270=on&87155=on&87453=on&87925=on&87934=on&87480=on&87047=on&87553=on&87311=on&87909=on&87436=on&87509=on&87912=on&87623=on&87444=on&87129=on&87371=on&87645=on&87022=on&87127=on&87828=on&87121=on&87938=on&87791=on&87448=on';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// search for td's with contains METAR
$metars = $xpath->query('//td[contains(text(), "METAR")]');
if($metars->length <= 0) {
    echo 'no metars found';
    exit;
}

$data = array();
foreach($metars as $metar) {
    $data[] = $metar->nodeValue;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for! thanks! have a nice weekend